# IBM Natural Language Understanding Tutorial Issue

Tags: ibm-watson, nlu

I'm trying to do the "Create an artificial intelligence bookmark organizer for the Chrome browser" tutorial found [AT THIS LINK](https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/smart-bookmark-plugin-using-watson-nlu/)

I'm using a Mac.  Put the folder structure together.  Signed up with the IBM developer site as required.  When I try to load the extension into Chrome using the "Load unpacked" function in Google I get the following error:

Could not load icon 'https://s3.us.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud/developer/default/tutorials/smart-bookmark-plugin-using-watson-nlu/images/ibmwatson.png' specified in 'icons'.
Could not load manifest.

The .png file is there. The .json file can load it from:
"https://s3.us.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud/developer/default/tutorials/smart-bookmark-plugin-using-watson-nlu/images/ibmwatson.png"
},
anyway.

Curl is installed.

I'm using the Lite version of NLU.   I cut and pasted the source directly from IBM.  Its all there at the link.

I tried making sure the files I created were all named correctly.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.